# Laravel 4 - php artisan migrate error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

when I run php artisan migrate I receive this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function J20\Uuid\openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() i n C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site\vendor\j20\php-uuid\src\ J20\Uuid\Uuid.php on line 32
```

I'm trying to install this app, https://github.com/andrew13/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site

I appreciate any help, since I have no idea how to deal with something in the vendor dir halting migrations.

Comment: Sounds like you need the `openssl` extension enabled. Enable it if it isn't already and then restart Apache.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Lewis, it was exactly that. I just don't understand why xampp wouldn't come with openssl already enabled.

Comment: I think that's just a PHP thing actually.

Comment: Yes, I meant the php installed from xampp.

Comment: @JasonLewis could you please add it as answer so people can upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you enable the `openssl` extension in your `PHP.ini` file by removing the comment from the following line.

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

So that it looks like this.

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Then restart Apache to make sure the changes take effect.